# phpMyAdmin configuration issues

Tags: configuration, phpmyadmin, xampp

I have just installed xampp server and after that i want to create my database via phpMyAdmin but i faced some configuration problems about these lines

```
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['users'] ...   not OK [ Documentation ]
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['usergroups'] ...  not OK [ Documentation ]
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['navigationhiding'] ...    not OK [ Documentation ]
```

So i made some researchs, i have created missing tables such as users, usergroups and navigationhiding and also i made neccesary changes in config.inc.php file as follows

```
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['users'] = 'pma_users';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['usergroups'] = 'pma_usergroups';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['navigationhiding'] = 'pma_navigationhiding';
```

After all these changes nothing is fixed. What can i do to fix this problem ? Any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your best options would be to remove and re-install again. That saves you time.